# Xinetd error service/protocol combination not in /etc/services

Tags: service, xinetd

Trying to create a simple xinetd style server without needing to create a full service first. I have the following file which is located at `/etc/xinetd.d/myscript`:

```
service tester
{
        disable = no
        socket_type     = stream
        protocol        = tcp
        port            = 8087
        wait            = no
        user            = root
        server          = /root/prog
}
```

but I keep getting the following error when restarting xinetd:
`service/protocol combination not in /etc/services`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to add `type = UNLISTED` as seen below, and as discussed at https://www.redhat.com/archives/fedora-legacy-list/2004-October/msg00146.html

```
service tester
{
        disable = no
        socket_type     = stream
        protocol        = tcp
        port            = 8087
        wait            = no
        user            = root
        server          = /root/prog
        type            = UNLISTED
}
```